# Significance of lip end curve

Tags: evolution, human-anatomy

What is significance of curve at point where lips meet, how it is determined and what effects it has on attraction and other factors? For some people it is a downward curve, for others it's an upward curve, while for some it is straight.

Is it genetic?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be called as a trait, since that region is highly mobile and changes according to emotions. But its well known that it gives an impression of downward curve in oldage.

Comment: @JM97 it is my observation that when lips are closed some people do have upper curves while most has downward, i thing upward and straight one is more attractive, so may be it is a trait. I checked on my self too, you can check on urself too.

Comment: this may help you:http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1003375